# Browsers won't load pages other than Google and Gmail

Tags: network, web-browser

I have a MacBook with OS X 10.6.8 and I am getting "no data received" on Google Chrome, "the connection was reset" on Firefox and "cant open the page" on Safari.

Google search engine works on Chrome and Firefox but nothing on Safari. Scanned the system with my antivirus and found no issues. Cleared the cookies and cache on all browsers and main system with no change. Mac Office did an update prior to this problem but can't seem to get out of this.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can start the process of elimination. If you are wifi can you switch to ethernet or vice versa? Are the other computers on the same local network able to connect?

Based on my experience, I can guess that hardware is beginning to fail somewhere. A switch, router or your network adapter. Have you rebooted all of those?

Comment: I have tried that; went from wifi to ethernet and rebooted my routers with still the same problems. I also have other computers on the same network both wifi and ethernet and they work fine. I dont know what else to do

Comment: How are the IP addresses assigned? Is it possible that two machines are sharing the same address? You may want to open the "Console" app and see if any of the messages relate.

Comment: I have found the problem. It was the anti virus program "Sophos". I was told by a friend of mine that Sophos has a habit of blocking "HTTP" sites. So when i got home i un-installed it and rebooted the system and everything works fine. Thanks for all your support